# Can I add y-axis labels on a horizontal barchart using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, axis-labels

I'm using the `pandas` wrapper around matplotlib to create a horizontal barchart and would like to add labels to the y-axis.

Sadly it doesn't seem to be as simple as just adding a `labels=df['Labels']` parameter as we can with pie charts.

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['A', 1, 2], ['B', 2, 3], ['C', 3, 4]]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Label', 'Col1', 'Col2'])
df.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

Is this possible in `pandas` alone or am I going to have to move into `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out what the problem is. If we set the 'Label' column as the index then the y-axis is labelled automatically.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=['Label', 'Col1', 'Col2'])
df.index = df['Label']
df.plot(kind='barh')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the DataFrame is not required. You can set the labels with `plt.yticks` after you have created the plot:

```
plt.yticks(range(3),df['Label'])
```